# Extracting kubernetes pod name using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, grep, kubectl

I want to extract a pod name from a list of pods available on kubernetes.
For example, for the following command

> kubectl get pods -n namespace

```
NAME          READY   STATUS            RESTARTS   AGE
pod1          1/1     Running           2          46d
pod2          1/1     Running           0          46d
test-pod3-yy  0/1     ImagePullBackOff  0          338d
test-pod3-xx  1/1     Running           0          255d
```

I want to extract pod `test-pod3-xx` using shell script. Currently this is the command that I'm using

```
POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -n namespace | grep testpod-3 | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

With this I get both the pods `test-pod3-yy` and `test-pod3-xx` but I want to extract the pod that is in running state. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `field-selector` and check for running only:

`--field-selector=status.phase=Running`

You could also use the `-o name` flag, to get only the names. With that you'll get:

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n namespace -o name --field-selector=status.phase=Running
pod/pod1
pod/pod2
pod/test-pod3-xx
```

Comment: Including --field-selector=status.phase=Running worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

kubectl get pods -n namespace > stack

while read line
do
[[ -n $(sed -n '/Running/p' "${line}" ]] && echo "${line}"
done < stack
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.